# Anti-derivative of $\sin^2(t)$

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I calculate the anti-derivative of $ \int \sin^2(t) \; dt $ without the help of other sources? Do I have to memorize different equivalences of sin(t) or is there a way to solve it without prior knowledge?

Comment: What does other sources exactly mean?

Comment: Personally, I'd go with $\cos(2t)=1-2\sin^2t$, but perhaps this falls under "memorise different equivalences".

Comment: The standard way is to use a double-angle identity. Alternately, we can integrate by parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that: $$\sin^2 t=\frac 1 2 -\frac 1 2 \cos (2t)$$

$$\frac t 2-\frac 1 2\int \cos (2t)=\frac t 2-\frac {\sin(2t)}{4}+\mathcal C$$

Comment: Can you show me the derivation / conversion from the left to the right side?

Comment: @deranor See [double-angle identity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html)

Comment: oh, now I see it, thanks! A photographic memory would be nice ...